# How to prevent iPhone from muting ringtone by side switch?

Tags: iphone, ios

The software side configuration of the side switch on iPhones (unlike iPads) was in one of the last iOS betas, but didn't make it through.

Is there any other trick to prevent an iPhone from being accidentally muted via the side switch?

Although convenient, I don't need the side switch to lock screen orientation - I just don't want to miss calls because it switched to "mute" in the pocket.

Apart from applying glue, that is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put, you can’t.

The best you can do is to make sure **Settings** → **Sounds & Haptics** → **Vibrate on Silent** is switched *On*. You can’t otherwise override the hardware mute switch.

You joked about applying glue, but a hardware solution does exist in the form of a case. With many iPhone cases, including Apple’s own Leather and Silicone Cases, surround the hardware Mute switch. Recessed in such a way, it becomes harder to switch off by accident.

Or you can also get an WATCH…

Comment: I had a good experience with super glue! After a year or so I sold the phone and removed the glue with specialized remover. No issues.

Comment: But what is even better: a "book" case for the phone. It protects the switch all around.